# jQuery run one group of functions after another

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, promise, jquery-callback

I have two groups of functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    // First group of functions    
    getCountry(id);

    // Second group of functions  
    getResult(id, 'all');

});
```

Within each group, functions are Ajax calls and chained together. It means that `getCountry()` is run first and calls `getRegion()` on `success` Ajax property, then  `getRegion()` calls `getTown()` on `success` Ajax property and so on. These functions are used to fill a form dropdown lists (selects). I will then get the towns of the region of the country I have selected.

I need the form lists to be filled before I run the `getResult()` function.

I don't want to call `getResult()` inside `getCountry()` because I also have to call `getResult()` if user changes selected options after the page is loaded. In this case `getResult()` will take various parameters other than `'all'`.

I'm looking for a simple way to re-write my `$(document).ready(function()` in order to say:

1. First: run `getCountry()` and its depending functions
2. then run `getResult()` and its depending functions

I'm getting a bit lost in jQuery doc about callbacks and `promise()`. I would really appreciate some help to allow me going ahead, knowing that I will come back to the doc seriously later on.

Comment: Provide the reference of `getResult` to the `getCountry` function and call it when all your AJAX requests have finished.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment...

Comment: Like @RoryMcCrossan said, send a reference of getResult in getCountry. E.g. getCountry(id, 'all', getResult). And amend getCountry definition to include another parameter like getCountry(id, param2, resultCallback). Once your processing of getCountry method gets finished then make a call to getResult like resultCallback(); inside that.

Comment: ` var id = $(this).attr('id');` is wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum : what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Deferred Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

```
// Create a deferred object
var deferred = $.Deferred();
```

Define the function to be called on deferred object resolution

```
// This function executes as soon as the deferred object gets resolved
deferred.done(function(value) {
   getResult(id, 'all');
});
```

On the callback of the last function of getCountry() group, resolve the deferred object:

```
// Resolve the deferred object
deferred.resolve(response);
```

Check this [article](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/)

Comment: Nice article @kapantzak. Include lots of details to understand the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try using deferred like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    // First group of functions    
    getCountry(id);  //Inside getCountry method, make a call to deferred.resolve();

    // Second group of functions  
    //Now make call to getResult only when promise is resolved.
    deferred.done(function(result){
        getResult(id, 'all');
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks like a mistake.  `deferred.done()` will be called before `getCountry` has completed.

Comment: @danh the intention is that it's *deferred* until getCountry is done.  although it's not exactly clear.  Would be clearer if `getCountry` returned the $.ajax call and did `var dferred = getCountry(id)`

Comment: Presumingly, getCountry is not returning any Ajax, instead making more than one Ajax calls inside. Either to club all the Ajax calls inside getCountry into a single promiseand return. Or resolve deferred object inside getCountry like i suggested. Please correct me if am wrong here.

Comment: What do you mean by *'inside getCountry method'* ? Do I have to place the `deferred.resolve()` within `getCountry()` function or within last function to be run in that group, ie `getTown()` ? Do I have to place it within `$.ajax()` or not? Thanks...

Comment: @wiltomap Ideal usecase would be to wait till all the sub functions of getCountry are finished using $.when() method. E.g. inside your getCountry method,   var d1 = getRegion();  var d2 = getTown(); where getRegion and getTown methods return Ajax method (e.g. getTown(){  return $.ajax(settings);}). Now resolve the parent deferred when all these sub methods are finished processing. Like $.when(d1, d2).done(function(dd) {  deferred.resolve();});

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Deffered` from jQuery. To Quote the documentions

> The Deferred object, introduced in jQuery 1.5, is a chainable utility object created by calling the jQuery.Deferred() method. It can register multiple callbacks into callback queues, invoke callback queues, and relay the success or failure state of any synchronous or asynchronous function.
>
> The Deferred object is chainable, similar to the way a jQuery object is chainable, but it has its own methods. After creating a Deferred object, you can use any of the methods below by either chaining directly from the object creation or saving the object in a variable and invoking one or more methods on that variable

try bellow code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var id = $(this).attr('id');
getCountry(id).done(getResult(id, 'all'));

});
function getCountry(id){
var dfd = $.Deferred(); 
// ur ajax calls and chains of onSuccessCalls
//call `resolve` on the deferred object, once you're done
Success:
    dfd.resolve();

// return the Deferred Object       
return dfd; 
}
```

Comment: I tried your proposal. I get a *TypeError: getCountry() is undefined* referring the line containing `getCountry(id).done(getResult(id, 'all'));`. I don't have this problem if I call `getCountry()` alone...